# search a list for a keyword

Tags: ocaml

Can anyone show me a working example of searching for an item in a list using `List.find` .. and print "found" if it was found.

Surprisingly, I have found no example of its usage in the documentation and none on google and only 1 on SO that confused me and gave errors. I just need a basic working example to start with.

Comment: I think people would be interested to know which one on SO you looked at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of downvotes? Shouldn't downvoters specify why in a comment or so?

Anyway, here's a solution.

Since List.find raises `Not_found` if the element is not found, you should use it within a `try ... with` block:

```
try
   let elem = List.find (fun i -> i = 1) [1;2;3] in
   print_endline ("Found integer " ^ (string_of_int elem))
with
   Not_found ->
      print_endline "Found no element"
```

The `(fun i -> i = 1)` part is a function that takes one element (from the list) and compare it with any condition should hold for the element you try to find. It could also be like `(fun i -> i > 2)` etc. Of course, if the list is a string list, you would use `(fun s -> s = "my_keyword")` or so. (You also might want to google about equality in OCaml.)

Comment: thanks for the reply :) do you also happen to know how to compare int references? I'm trying to compare a int reference to 1 and keep getting int reference expected :/

Comment: Yes, you must dereference the ref with !, like `let i = ref 2 in !i = 4`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to conserve the element found, you can use List.exists:

```
if(List.exists (fun i -> i = 1) [1;2;3]) 
    then print_endline ("Found") 
    else print_endline ("Not found")
```

Or List.mem:

```
if(List.mem 1 [1;2;3])
    then print_endline ("Found") 
    else print_endline ("Not found")
```